# PhantomJS PDF page break

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, page-break

I create a PDF report with header generated automatically by phantomjs. In the report I have a long div which contains text, blank lines, simple data tables etc.
Since I believe phantomjs might have problem with the page break, I calculate the page break manually, break up the long div into multiple divs with page break at the end of each div.

Here is my calculation in the jQuery(document).ready()

```
//pagination the Notes pages
if (encData.pnotes && encData.pnotes.length > 0) {
pageCnt++;
var $notes = jQuery('<div id="pageNotes" class="notes" style="width:100%;margin-top:100px;border:1px solid red">' + 
  pNotesString + '</div>');
$body.append($notes);
var height = 0;
var children = $notes.children();
var p = children.slice(0);
var pages = [];
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  if (height + children[i].offsetHeight < 1350)
    height += children[i].offsetHeight;
  else {
    pages.push([counter, i]);
    height = 0;
    counter = i;
  }
} 
pages.push([counter, children.length]);
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  //first notes page
  if (i == 0) {
    $notes.children().slice(pages[i][1]).remove();
    $notes.after('<div style="border:1px solid black;height:1px"></div><div id="pageNotesBreak" style="page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</div>');
  } 
  else {
    pageCnt++;
    var $new = jQuery('<div id="page' + pageCnt + '" class="notes" style="width:100%;margin-top:100px;border:1px solid blue"></div>');
    $new.append(p.slice(pages[i][0], pages[i][1]));
    $body.append($new);
    $body.append('<div style="border:1px solid black;height:1px"></div><div id="pageBreak' + pageCnt + '" style="page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</div>');
  }
}
```

The `"<div style='border:1px solid black;height:1px'>"` is just a silly marker to find where my page breaks are on the PDF.
1350px in the estimated height of objects where the page break should be created when I traverse all the children of the long div.

In Chrome, I see that I have a total of 5 pages.
But when it is rendered in PDF, the number of pages goes up to 6 or 7 depending the size of the font, the line height, etc.

Here is the image of the pages

[image: div content runs over header]

Does anyone know the cause of the problem? And how to solve it in general.